# What escape character is \u000a

Tags: unicode, escaping, character

what escape character is

```
\u000a
```

I would like it to be a quotation mark, but this gigantic unicode table I looked at did not account for this one

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Without looking at a Unicode table I would say this is a Line Feed (ASCII 10).

Answer (score 15):

Basically it's `\n`, [`nl = New line = \u000a`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart) in the ASCII table.

In Unicode it's a Line Feed:

- Line Feed: [`LF = \n = \u000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000A/index.htm)
- Carriage Return: [`CR = \r = \u000D`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000D/index.htm)

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Code_chart

Answer (score 0):

With the little bit of research and my understanding I can say it is a 16-bit number so. And every 4 nibbles represent in between 0 to f, so coming to the question it is 000a right. The rightmost nibble represents "a" which has a value of 10 in decimal. So the answer would be 10.