# LF in Kotlin language specification standard for what?

Tags: kotlin, lf

Recently I am learning Kotlin. When I read  Kotlin language specification, I meet some problems. I do not understand LF in Kotlin language specification standard for what?
In section "1.2.1 Whitespace and comments", LF show as below.
"LF: <unicode character Line Feed U+000A>"
So LF is short for what, and "unicode character Line Feed U+000A" is what?

Comment: LF is show for Line Feed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is already in the question: `unicode character Line Feed U+000A`

As that implies, LF stands for Line Feed. It's a character, with Unicode value U+000A. It's used<sup>*</sup> to separate lines within text files — so is treated as whitespace, and is mentioned in the whitespace section of the docs.

There's plenty of information about that character [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116899/what-escape-character-is-u000a), [on the official Unicode site](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=000A), [and](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/000A.html) [on](https://codepoints.net/U+000A?lang=en) [many](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_feed) [other](https://blog.loginradius.com/engineering/eol-end-of-line-or-newline-characters/) [sites](https://techexplorations.com/guides/arduino/programming/line-feeds-and-carriage-returns/) — all very easy to find with your favourite search engine.

(In fact, a web search is probably a much better place to start when learning a new language than from the language specification, which is highly technical and intended for people writing compilers and similar tools. Even better, start from [the official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html) — the ‘Basics’ section gives a quick intro, while the later sections go into full detail.)

---

<sup>(* Some platforms use only LF to separate lines; others use the CR character — carriage return, U+000D — followed by LF; and historically some used only CR.)</sup>